# how to start activity when android turned on?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have the next code:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    startActivityIntent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
    startActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityIntent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    context.startActivity(startActivityIntent);

}}
```

And the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"  android:enabled="true"  android:exported="false"  android:label="BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter >

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It works perfectly when I turn on the device the activity starts, but I think it take about 30 seconds, I think is too much time, I want to do something like the Famigo's app, when the device is turned on inmediately start.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to speed up this process. It takes 30 seconds on your device, because the program has to wait until your device is completely booted. Boot_Completed is the first notification that the system sends out after boot.

Google has done this intentionally to prevent apps from starting before the system is finished booting.

Answer (score 0):

the reciver calls BootCompleteReceiver, the reciver will start after the boot will complete.
it takes about 30 seconds.
you cant start the app before the OS!